# С чего начать написание демо сцен?

Tags: android, java

Хотел бы попробовать писать демосцены, потому как заинтересован в графике, особенно меня интересует написание по Android OS.

Comment: На хабре была статья про это, попробуйте связаться с автором. http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android/118544/

Answer (score 2):

Под Android не писал, но несколько общих советов дать попробую :)

1. Изучите графические возможности сабжа. Что оно может и чего не может на "железном" уровне. Определитесь, что Вам нравится, а с чем придется бороться (на будущее).
2. Разберитесь, как использовать упомянутые возможности, какие есть API, библиотеки, фреймворки. Определитесь, что именно Вы будете использовать.
3. Напишите простое приложение, выполняющее "захват экрана" с помощью выбранного Вами API. Убедитесь, что все работает как дОлжно.
4. Наконец - собственно начните писать демо - напишите сценарий (для начала - попроще), разберитесь, какой функционал будете задействовать, опишите нужные Вам примитивы и разработайте функции, которые будут их отрисовывать... Постройте демо...

Отдельно (можно параллельно) при необходимости, изучайте основы 3D графики. Могу посоветовать [demo.design 3D Programming FAQ](http://www.enlight.ru/faq3d/) - именно "основы" - т.е. не DirectX, не OpenGL, а база, на которой все это держится - (и все FAQ от demo.design) - ресурс довольно старенький, но от этого не менее актуальный...

Если нужно/интересно, вот [здесь](http://www.theprodukkt.com/demoscene) можно посмотреть хорошие примеры демо...